# How to include a EJS file in an <li>?

Tags: node.js, express, web, ejs

So, I'm trying to render an EJS file in `<li></li>` tags and I keep getting an error. Heres my code:

```
<ul id="forms">
  <li id="high">
    <% include ./forms/colleges %>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Do I need to convert this to a String or something?

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: Never mind I fixed it. But thanks anyway.

Comment: You're welcome. You might consider adding your solution for future readers.